# InstallShield for Windows: Error Diasnosis

Tags: installshield

I am attempting to make an installer for a Windows XP mass-updater. The purpose of this program is to install 75% of all of the updates Windows XP had over the years and run them automatically without having to go to Microsoft's website and install them all one at a time. This simply does that for you. My issue is when I attempt to build the release, I get two errors:

Error -1024: File AppDataFolder not found. Cannot stream the file into the Binary table
Error -3016: Falied to add Binary table New_Binary1 to package.

I tried to put all of the install executables to a CD, then made the builder target each one individually, and went from 88 errors to 2. I expected it to run smoothly and present me with a .exe file I can drag and drop into the CD and call it a day, but it presented me errors I have yet to decipher. I can still do what I wanted, but I want to be sure the resulting program is stable for a good release, and not unusable.